# How to disable this asp panel, which contains custom tree control specifed in script tag?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style="width:400px; height:400px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid black;">
   <div id="sliders" style="width:200px; height:200px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid black;">
       <div id="canDiv" style="width:400px; height:0px;" class="ygtv-checkbox"></div> 
   </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

//Script display static tree-------

```
<!-- Combo-handled YUI CSS files: --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.9.0/build/treeview/assets/skins/sam/treeview.css"> 

<!-- Combo-handled YUI JS files: --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js&2.9.0/build/connection/connection-min.js&2.9.0/build/treeview/treeview-min.js"></script>  

<!-- Combo-handled YUI JS files: --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js&2.9.0/build/treeview/treeview-min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
var tree;                  
var cnt;                    //counter
var mailbox=new Array();    // to store str
(function() { 
function treeInit() {
tree = new YAHOO.widget.TreeView("canDiv");     //create tree obj
var root = tree.getRoot();                        // get root element
var root1= new YAHOO.widget.TextNode("Node", root, false);
for (cnt=1;cnt<=20000;cnt++)
{
   mailbox[cnt] = new YAHOO.widget.TextNode("Node "+cnt, root1, false);

}
        tree.subscribe('clickEvent',tree.onEventToggleHighlight);      
        tree.setNodesProperty('propagateHighlightUp',true); 
        tree.setNodesProperty('propagateHighlightDown',true); 
  tree.render();


//alert("after tree render");

}//end of treeInit 
 YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", treeInit); 
})();
```

I tried to `Panel1.Enabled=false;` but didnt worked for me.. the tree control is of yahoo.. Now I'M tring on static tree.. when I would be clicking on button. It should disable the panel.

Any help would be great. thanks

Comment: you're not providing a good definition for 'disable' here.  

Setting the .Visible property to False on a server control typically keeps the control from being rendered on the page at all. 

The Enabled attribute has no effect on a panel, because it's not a recognized attribute for the DIV/TABLE tag in html (which the PANEL renders as) in the same way that it disallows user in put on a button or textbox.

Comment: Ok. But I required that Div to render tree at run time, so which control should i use? instead of panel? which will get disable on click event??

Comment: to guarantee that you get a div on the client, use the DIV HTML  control. handling the click event, is a matter of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Panel1.Enabled = False;` should work.

Try using `Visible` property

`Panel1.Visible=false`

Answer (score 0):

You might not be executing Panel1.Enabled = False; as it should work. Secondly you have nothing that should show you disable effect. I added the textboxes in your html and it is working fine.

**HTML side**

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style="width:400px; height:400px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid black;">
    panel <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
   <div id="sliders" style="width:200px; height:200px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid black;">
parent<asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <div id="canDiv" style="width:400px; height:0px;" class="ygtv-checkbox">child<asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div> 
   </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.Enabled = false;
}
```

As discussion with OP shows he wants to disable the controls add on client.

**HTML** add in panel

```
<input type="button" id="btndisable" />
```

**Javascript**

See [how to add jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery)

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#btndisable').click(function(){
        $('#Panel1 input').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled', true); 
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: in div I am rendering tree dyanmically,which is custom control of Yahoo.. & on click event I want it to be disabled

Comment: Yes It Is client side control, get rendered into DIV, I have added its code.. so u can have a look @ at..

Comment: Its not disabling Yahoo tree... It works fine for server side controls

Comment: You have to check what yahoo controls you have I just gave you an example, check yahoo code using veiw source of browser and you will need to use selector for those controls